# What's a good web crawler to download HTML pages?

Tags: html, web-crawler

I am looking for a web crawler/spider to download individual pages. What is a good (preferably free) product that supports this?

Comment: Please explain what makes this question a programming question? If it isn't, please read our [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to see what questions are acceptable here.

Comment: @Oded: Yea, this most likely belongs on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) or maybe [webmasters.stackexchange.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I can recommend [HTTrack](https://www.httrack.com/). The GUI will lead you through the options you have when setting up a website download. Interesting settings you may change are the scan rules (for including/excluding files/paths), the maximum mirroring depth, and if you want to download html files first. You can usually keep the other defaults. Per default rewrites the links so that the mirrored site can be browsed locally using a webbrowser. Site downloads can be restarted and then only files which do not already locally exist will be downloaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`wget`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget) or [`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/) come to mind. What exactly are your requirements? Do you need to recursively crawl pages, or just download specific URLs? `wget` can do both.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for WGET www.gnu.org/s/wget/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download a hole website then give [wget](http://www.gnu.org/s/wget/) a try. It has features to download recursively. If you need to manipulate headers and only download a few small files try [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) (or wget).
Should you need features like parallel downloading huge files I would suggest [aria2](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

A list of open source crawlers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler#Open-source_crawlers